# Applying one command to list in text file

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, robocopy, list

Assuming I have a list of PCs in a text file, how would I go about running the same command on each pc in the list?

For example, say my list is this:

- ln1
- ln2
- ln3
- ln4

And my command is this:

- robocopy \\SRC\storeman\bitmaps \\%LN#%\storeman\bitmaps /xo ***(%ln#% being the PCs from the list)***

With there being hundreds of PCs to apply this to, we don't want to hard-code the pc names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in powershell

```
$arrComputers = get-content c:\path\to\file.txt 

foreach($strComputerin $arrComputers){   
robocopy \\SRC\storeman\bitmaps \\$strComputer\storeman\bitmaps /xo  
}
```

Comment: That'll do it! I needed it for a batch file and I forgot to specify that but I can absolutely make this work. Much appreciated!